# How to include page margin into header and footer in memoir?

Tags: header-footer, margins, memoir, marginpar

I wonder how I can achieve the following two things:

1. I want to have defined page margins for the use of `\marginpar` notes and comments. The problem is that, although I use memoir with twoside option the oddside outer margin and the evenside outer margin differ. I want the outer margins to be exactly the same on both, odd and even pages (for example to have 6 cm outer margins and 2 cm inner margins).
2. I would like to extend the header and footer to include the outer margin (both marginsep and marginwidth). As I understand the handbook this could be done using the `companion` pagestyle, but I prefer the default chapter style (i.e. its font, style, shape, no rule, etc.). How can I modify the chapter pagestyle to make header and footer extend into the margin area? Btw.: I did try to modify `headwidth` by playing with the `companion`style definition from the memoir handbook. But I had no success:

I tried this:

```
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
 \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
 \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

 \copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
 \makerunningwidth{chapter}{\headwidth}
```

Here is a MWE. I tried to shorten it a bit.

```
\documentclass[12pt,foliopaper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


%*****************Margins and MarginNotes******************

\setmarginnotes{10pt}{5cm}{6pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{0.9\textwidth}
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\-\oldmarginpar[\footnotesize #1]%
{\raggedright\footnotesize #1}}

%*******************Header & Footer***********************
 \nouppercaseheads 
%***********************Document*******************
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\title{\textbf{Title}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\kant[12]
\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[8]
\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[7]\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\section{Section 1}
\kant[7]


\chapterstyle{default}
\newpage

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) It is not at all clear what you want to do. (2) Please make that example *minimal*

Comment: I hope I could clarify my problem and I shortened the MWE.

Answer (score 2):

I used the [geometry](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ctan.org%2Fpkg%2Fgeometry&ei=JCNzVb2rCMufNvD7gYAI&usg=AFQjCNFEpLpsjTqhMrVG170dLBu0i4-MYA&bvm=bv.95039771,d.eXY) to properly set the margin sizes (6 outer, 2 inner). Remember the `\headwidth` must come **after** the geometry margins definition.
As pointed by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) it's much easier and cleaner to do it with memoir companion style.
If you want the first chapter page to have same style just add `\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{companion}` after the \pagestyle.
Screenshot in Adobe Acrobat: [image: memoir companion wide header]

```
\documentclass[12pt,foliopaper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

%*****************Margins and MarginNotes******************

\usepackage[outer=6cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=1cm]{geometry}

%*******************Header & Footer***********************

\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

 \nouppercaseheads 
%***********************Document*******************
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\title{\textbf{Title}}

\pagestyle{companion}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\kant[12]
\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[8]
\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\kant[7]\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\section{Section 1}
\kant[7]
\marginpar{The reader should be careful to observe that the objects in space and time are the clue to the discovery of, certainly, our a priori knowledge, by means of analytic unity.}
\chapterstyle{default}
\newpage

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: This can easily be done without fancyhdr, see the source for the companion pagestyle

Comment: How can we add break to the headerrule, at the place of white space between text and marginpar?

Comment: @marko I don't know if I understand, but you can simply use ``\setlength{\headsep}{5cm} `` for example to increase the space.
If that doesn't help, please make a new question :).